# Creation of element failed in GPE

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

In Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE), if I create a new web application project and un-select `Generate project sample code`, I get a `Creation of Element Failed` error saying `web.xml` already exists.

It all works fine if I select sample code generation. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with GAE on eclipse 3.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I uncheck the "Use Google Web Toolkit SDK" option.

Comment: Oh... so the problem is related to the GWT SDK

Comment: @SaadFarooq Yes, GWT does appear to be the culprit. Were you able to find another work around?

Comment: Nope... but don't see what can be done... I'll see if there is an issue raised on this or raise one